# WebAPI serializer serializes base class instead of kludgy child class

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net, datacontractserializer

The class that I need gets serialized as a web service response body.

The problem is, the properties from the base class get serialized along with it, and I can't have that for this service.

I need to block those properties from being serialized on only this subclass. So I tried hiding the properties using `new` but the base class properties are still being serialized (i.e. "Hello, world" is in the resulting http response body):

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get { return "Hello, world"; } }
}

public class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public new string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

this gets returned via something like this:

`return myHttpRequestMessage.CreateResponse(myStatusCode, myChildClassInstance);`

So two questions

- What up with that? Why isn't it honoring the child class with its decorations?
- Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve (which is preventing the decorated properties from being serialized?

I know it's a total kludge, but until I have the time to fix the deeper issue (which is the operation that's forcing this inheritance), this is what I have to work with.

Comment: How do you initialize the instance of the child class?

Comment: `[Serializable]` declaration on your class?

Comment: Your test case reproduces for Json.Net, but not for `DataContractJsonSerializer`, which serializes the child property in preference to the parent.  Does that help?

Comment: Assuming you are using Json.NET, this is possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887787/jsonpropertyattribute-ignored-on-private-property-in-derived-class

Comment: I'm using the default serializer which I think uses json.net for json and datacontractserializer for xml. Need to support both. I'm testing json first, I hadn't tried xml specifically. @dbc is that what you're saying? That if it were xml, it'd be fine? @robert It is is just `var childInstance = new ChildClass()`. Nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

In order to ignore a property from the base class you could override this property in the derived class and decorate it with [JsonIgnoreAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm):

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual string MyProperty { get { return "Hello, world"; } }
}

public class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public override string MyProperty { get; }
}
```

You get an empty json object serializing it:

```
Debug.Assert(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyChildClass()) == "{}");
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise other people have posted similar solutions to this but I thought I'd give a bit more background to the issue as well.
The issue you are having is that you are hiding the property of the base class instead of overriding it.

The way the serializer works is that it uses reflection to look through your objects, and find the properties and values, which it uses to build its output.

For the purposes of reflection, Hiding essentially creates a second property with the same name as the original. The original property is still visible to reflection however.
Overriding on the other hand essentially redefines the base property.

This code example in .Net Fiddle shows the difference between a class with a hidden property and a class with an overridden one. You can see that in the hidden class reflection lists both properties but in the overridden class it only lists the properties of the overridden property.

[Hidden Vs overridden](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h6abXl)

(Most)Serializers are semi smart, if you try and serialize a child class that hides a property in a parent class, the serializer should serialize just the property of the child class. The issue however occurs in your case in that although you're telling the serializer to ignore the property in the child class, reflection has returned both the child and parent properties. This now leaves the serializer free to serialize the property from the parent class instead (which does not have an ignore attribute on it).

If you override the class however the serializer only has access to the child class and its properties and so the ignored properties of the parent class are not serialized.

The first thing you need to do is set the property you wish to override on your base class to virtual. This means that it is able to be overridden if required. Like so:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get { return "Hello, world"; } }
}
```

Once this is done you can now override the property in the child class and apply appropriate attributes to it. Like so:

```
public class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public new string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Generally in the scope of Inheritance and serialization, I'd only hide a property in a base class if I wanted to change its datatype.

Answer (score -1):

**JSON**

If you are using JSON.NET (which is a default JSON serializer in Web.API), then you will probably need to use custom `ContractResolver`. Answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588022/exclude-property-from-serialization-via-custom-attribute-json-net/16647343#16647343) has a good examples of creating such type of class. In the following examples I will use `IgnorableSerializerContractResolver` from one of the answers.

Now you can register it in `Global.asax`:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new IgnorableSerializerContractResolver()
    .Ignore<MyBaseClass>(x => x.MyProperty);
```

If you already using some contract resolver (for example [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm)) then you will need to combine them somehow.

**XML**

I don't know what type (`DataContractSerializer` or `XmlSerializer`) of XML serialization are you using, but as I know, `DataContractSerializer` doesn't allow to exclude properties in runtime. You will need to use `XmlSerializer`. You can set custom serializers per type:

```
var xmlOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
var xmlAttr = new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true };
xmlOver.Add(typeof(MyBaseClass), "MyProperty", xmlAttr);

var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.SetSerializer<MyChildClass>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyChildClass), xmlOver));
```

**Siple way**

If you have access to your `MyBaseClass` and allowed to do some changes, then you can solve your problem using `Data` attributes:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

In this case you can use default serializers (JSON.NET for JSON and `DataContractSerializer` for XML) and it will be solved for you automatically. Please note that you **must** add `DataContract` to `MyBaseClass`, or otherwise XML serialization will fail.

Comment: Do you need the same functionality for XML?

Comment: I do. I will try this out when I'm back in the office tomorrow.