# Json.Net not deserializing derived object that hides base property when posting with form data

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization, form-data

I have a WebApi Controller method that accepts a derived class:

```
    //Controller Method
    public IHttpActionResult Test(DerivedClass m)
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }

    //base class
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
    }

    //derived class
    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public new int? Id { get; set; }
    }
```

I am posting with Id = 1

If I POST to this controller method with JSON data type it works fine (I get an object with Id=1), but if I send x-www-form-urlencoded data then the object is null.

Now, if I change the controller method to accept the BaseClass and use x-www-form-urlencoded data then the object is not null (Id=1).  Also, if I modify the Derived class and remove the new int? property it works fine as well.

This is leading me to believe there is an issue with Json.Net not deserializing x-www-form-urlencoded data to objects that hide derived class properties. Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: JSON.Net doesn't deserialize `x-www-form-urlencoded` data at all; that isn't JSON.

Comment: Mixing shadowed properties with deserialization is a very bad idea, as you're beginning to discover (eg, code that uses the base class will break).  Don't do that.

Comment: Right, correction:  this isn't an issue with Json.Net it is Asp.Net... I dont see this issue with shadow properties in Json.Net

Comment: This question seems very similar to [JsonPropertyAttribute ignored on private property in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27887787/3744182).  Does `PreferDerivedPropertyContractResolver` from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27892664/3744182) meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that the nullable int property will have a different signature from non-nullable, so you may not be actually overriding the property if that was your intention.

Comment: No; that's what `new` means, and is what is causing the problem.